# Collect to a Map in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a Hive table such as

```
id  |  value
-------------
A      1
A      2
B      3
A      4
B      5
```

Essentially, I want to mimic Python's `defaultdict(list)` and create a map with `id` as the keys and `value` as the values.

**Query:**

```
select COLLECT_TO_A_MAP(id, value)
from table
```

**Output:**

```
{A:[1,2,4], B:[3,5]}
```

I tried using [klout's](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/tree/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect) `CollectUDAF()` but it appears this will not append the values to an array, it will just update them.  Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Here is a more detailed description so I can avoid answers referencing that I try functions in the Hive documentation.  Suppose I have a table

```
num    |id    |value
____________________
1       A      1
1       A      2
1       B      3
2       A      4
2       B      5
2       B      6
```

What I am looking for is for a UDAF that provides this output

```
num     |new_map
________________________
1       {A:[1,2], B:[3]}
2       {A:[4], B:[5,6]}
```

To this query

```
select num
      ,COLLECT_TO_A_MAP(id, value) as new_map
from table
group by num
```

There is a workaround to achieve this.  It can be mimicked by using *Klout's* (see above referenced UDAF) `CollectUDAF()` in a query such as

```
add jar '~/brickhouse/target/brickhouse-0.6.0.jar'
create temporary function collect as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

select num
       ,collect(id_array, value_array) as new_map
from (
      select collect_list(id) as id_array
            ,collect_list(value) as value_array
            ,num
      from table
      group by num
     ) A
group by num
```

However, I would rather not write a nested query.

**EDIT #2**

(As referenced in my original question) I have already tried using *Klout's* `CollectUDAF()`, even in the instance where you pass it two parameter and it creates a map.  The output from that is (if applied to the dataset in my 1st edit)

```
1    {A:2, B:3}
2    {A:4, B:6}
```

As stated in my original question, it doesn't collect the values to an array it just collects the last one (or updates the array).

Answer (score 2):

Use the collect UDF in Brickhouse (http://github.com/klout/brickhouse )

It is exactly what you need. Brickhouse's 'collect' returns a list if one parameter is used, and a map if two parameters are used.

Answer (score 1):

the CollectUDAF in Brickhouse (http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) will get you there.

regarding your comment **EDIT #2**:

first, collect the values to a list, then collect the k,v pairs to a map:

```
select
    num,
    collectUDAF(id, values) as new_map
from
    (
    SELECT
        num,
        id,
        collect_set(value) as values
    FROM
        tbl
    GROUP BY
        num,
        id
    ) as sub
GROUP BY
    num
```

will return

```
num  | new_map
________________________
1      {A:[1,2], B:[3]}
2      {A:[4], B:[5,6]}
```

Comment: You basically just took what I wrote in my question and put that as an answer.  I fail to see how this answers the question.

Comment: @GoBrewers14: your query in EDIT1 was not quite correct. if you want to do it without a nested query, then you probably would have to create your own UDAF, using one of the existing ones as basis. Should be quite straightforward. Apart from that I am quite sure that there is no way to do it in vanilla hive without a nested query at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care about the order in which the values appear, you could use the collect_set() UDAF that comes with Hive.

```
SELECT id, collect_set(value) FROM table GROUP BY id;
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: How does this solve my issue?  It doesn't create a Map and it only collects distinct objects.

Comment: From documentation, ``collect_set`` returns an ``array`` not a map.

Answer (score -1):

Your current query groups by num in both the inner and outer query -- you need to group by `id` in the inner query to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: 'id' is inside an aggregate function

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/CollectUDAF.java#L55

see brickhouse udaf,when args num larger than 1, MapCollectUDAFEvaluator would be used.

```
add jar */brickhouse.jar ;
create temporary function collect  as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';
select 
collect(a,b)
from( select 1232123 a,21 b 
    union all select 123 a,23 b)a;


result:{1232123:21,123:23}
```