# Spark/Hive UDAF for distinct values by key

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, hiveql

In big data processing it is often desirable to "sketch" summaries of groups *without* changing the existing query structure (grouping, subqueries, etc.). In Spark SQL (and HiveQL) `collect_set` is an example of a UDAF that does this. It builds an array of the unique values of a column per group.

I am looking for a UDAF that builds a map of the unique values from column A for each unique value of column B. For example, given

```
date user_id category revenue  
1/1  1       a        1  
1/1  2       b        0  
1/1  3       a        0  
1/2  2       b        10  
1/2  3       a        0  
1/2  4       b        1
```

the query

```sql
select date, collect_set_by_key(category, user_id) as distinct_user_ids_by_category
from tbl
group by date
order by date
```

should generate

```
date distinct_user_ids_by_category
1/1  {a: [1, 3], b: [2]}
1/2  {a: [3], b: [2, 4]}
```

[Collect to a Map in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826530/collect-to-a-map-in-hive) asks for the same outcome but does not require the solution to be via a single UDAF without changes to query structure, which makes this question substantially different.

My deployment environment is Spark 2.1 so a Hive UDAF or a native Spark UDAF would work equally well. I've checked brickhouse, hivemall and a few other libraries with Hive UDAFs but have not found a function that does this.

Comment: This question looks pretty similiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826530/collect-to-a-map-in-hive

Comment: @Mariusz that question does not impose a hard requirement that the solution is a UDAF and that the query structure is not changed.

Comment: What do you mean no changes to grouping. Can you explain a little more on what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AssafMendelson I mean I am looking for a UDAF that does what the question asks and operates completely independently of the query structure. The [Collect to a Map in Hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826530/collect-to-a-map-in-hive) question asks for the outcome but does not disallow changes to query structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, I think a UDAF like this exists in my fork of brickhouse, called `gather`  ( https://github.com/jeromebanks/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/GatherUDAF.java ) but not in the klout version. I haven't been very good about merging back to the klout repo. I think the list can contain duplicates, if multiple records are seen.

```
SELECT date, gather( category, user_id )
FROM tbl
GROUP BY date;
```

This can also be done with multiple collects, as mentioned in the link to the other question, but I think `gather` might be more efficient, and a little easier to use.

Comment: If I understand what `gather` does correctly, the number of entries across all values of the resulting map will equal the number of (non-null?) `user_id` rows. Is that accurate?